# Is there a way to to check if a picture was taken on that iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I was wondering if there was a way to check if a photo was taken on the iphone the user is using. Is there some type of metadata the image has that only that iphone would make for it? I'm trying to find a way to check if photos were taken on an iphone 6 and only an iphone 6.

Comment: No (as far as "that phone"), that would be a blatant breach of identity/tracking concerns. If there is any additional data in in the pictures it will be located in the EXIF data, which may differ but it'll likely be mainly per photo software/iOS version I suspect.

Comment: @user2864740 It wouldn't be a breach of identity, because EXIF data doesn't store a unique identifier for each device a picture was taken from. EXIF data does contain camera manufacturer and model though.

Comment: @Milo That was for "taken on *that* iPhone" and "*the* iphone the user is using" (eg. there is no magical UUID embedded) as opposed to "taken *on* an iphone 6".

Comment: @user2864740 The OP clearly states at the end "check if photos were taken on an iphone 6 and only an iphone 6". By that phone I think he means that type of phone.

Comment: @Milo The OP specifies two things. My comments are to *draw attention to this ambiguity* while providing a useful start of research.

Comment: @user2864740 model and manufacturer are stored in the TIFF dictionary in iOS.

Answer (score 2):

Infact, the model and manufacturer data aren't stored in the EXIF data at all, actually it is stored in the *TIFF* data (at least on the iPhone). Here's how to retrieve that data and specifically the model as a string, provided the TIFF data exists:

```
NSString *myPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IMG_0002" ofType:@"jpg"];
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPath];
CGImageSourceRef sourceRef = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)myURL, NULL);

NSDictionary *metadata = (__bridge id)CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(sourceRef, 0, NULL);
NSDictionary *TIFFdata = [metadata objectForKey:(__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyTIFFDictionary];
NSString *model = [TIFFdata objectForKey:(__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyTIFFModel];
```

On my 5S, model is "iPhone 5S", which you can most likely assume will be "iPhone 6" on an iPhone 6.

NOTE: If you have the image as a UIImage, do not get the data by doing `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` you will lose a lot of metadata, including most of the TIFF.